# Tools to display test servers online/offline, db instance etc?

Tags: tools, test-strategy, metrics

Is there anything in the market at present, where you can add a list of servers (`Windows/IIS`) perhaps with a `database` instance linked to them (`SQL server`), that can display a dashboard with which servers are `online/offline`, their respective `IP's` and database instance etc, possibly a release version too?

Is it OK if I have to manually add this data initially?

I want to have a `dashboard` of `QA servers` (20+ servers), that is easy to see at a glance if they are on, and what release version they are on etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've used [Nagios Core](https://www.nagios.org/projects/nagios-core/) for this before and it sounds ideal for your needs.  It can easily monitor almost anything on a remote machine, such as Disk Space, CPU usage, Downtime, Memory usage, Database usage... probably more than you would ever need, and you can get it to email if certain conditions are met.  It does have a steep learning curve if you are not that familiar with Linux, but it is worth the effort.

For something Windows based, I have used [Spiceworks Network Monitor](https://www.spiceworks.com/free-network-monitoring-management-software/) as well, although it was rather resource intensive for my liking and didn't feel as feature rich as Nagios.